# How to show images as Web url in .Net Core 3

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Currently I have a folder under bin which gets created and all the images are copied from google drive to local directory. This is a .net Core 3.1 project. Now, is it possible to send the url of an image as a response. Url will be the url of the api. So response can be like: http://www.test.com/files/test.png

I tried to study this one:

https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html

and also tried to inject IWebHostingEnvironment in controller. This also doesnt work: _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath.

```
public class ServiceManager : IServiceManager
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public ServiceManager(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        EnsureArg.IsNotNull(webHostEnvironment, nameof(webHostEnvironment));
        
        _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    //localUrlPath can be \\test\\images\test.png
    public string GetImageUrl(string localUrlPath)
    {
      EnsureArg.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace(localUrlPath);
      localUrlPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, localUrl);
      return localUrlPath;
    }
    // expected url is http://10.10.10/test/images/test.png
 }
```

Comment: Could you show a reproducible example of how yoiu have tried to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I checked out the documentation. It seems like static files when used under default conditions revert to the default files found (ie. default.htm, index.htm etc).

Comment: add ur controller code

Comment: in controller i just call GetImageUrl